# Split method in mapreduce

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I have an input file:

```
    101 Alice   23  female  IT  45
    102 Bob 34  male    Finance 89
    103 Chris   67  male    IT  97
```

My mapper:

```
    package EmpCtcPack;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;

    public class EmpctcMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{

    private Text MKey=new Text();
    private Text MValue=new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
         ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String tempKey= new String();
    String tempValue=new String();

    try
    {
        tempValue=value.toString();
        tempKey=value.toString().split("    ")[3];

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MKey.set(tempKey);
    MValue.set(tempValue);

    context.write(MKey, MValue);
    }
    }
```

My Reducer:

```
    package EmpCtcPack;

   import java.io.IOException;

   import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
   import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
   import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
   import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;

   public class EmpCtcReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {

   private Text RValue=new Text();
   private Text RKey= new Text();

   public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, 
            Context context
            ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Integer i= new Integer(0);              
    String s=new String();      
    Integer t=new Integer(0);
    Text text=new Text();


    try
    {
        for (Text val : values)
        {   


            String arr[]=val.toString().split(" ");
            s=arr[3];
            text.set(s);

            context.write(key, text);

        }   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
   }
```

The problem is in split method.

When I try to get `arr[0]`, it works fine and I get the id number (*101, 102 and so on*).

But if I try to get `arr[1]` or `arr[2]` I get **0**. 
Does anyone has any idea why it works so?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Can you please show the piece of code where you are using arr[0], arr[1], etc?

Comment: I mean in the line s=arr[3], if it is s=arr[0], than I get the id number, if there is any other index (1,2,3...), than I get just 0

Comment: can you add your driver class? I am thinking you have used combiner in your driver class which you don't need in this case.

Comment: Yes, after removing combiner it works fine now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used combiner in your driver class which you don't need in this case.

try to use regEx in `split():`

```
value.toString().split("\\t+"); //if split-en by multiple tabs
value.toString().split("\\t");   //if split-en by single tab
```

Comment: the fields are split-en by tab, I tried "\\s+", it did not help

Comment: @Mariia - see update! - try `\\t` or `\\t+` as explained in answer

Comment: does not help unfortunately

Comment: did you make this change in both `mapper` and `reducer` methods?

Comment: the issue was the combiner class, which I do not need here

Comment: @Mariia - great - Consider accepting my solution as an answer, up vote it : ) [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - click on correct sign and up arrow on left `< 0 >`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It was with the combiner class. I removed the combiner class and it works fine now. Thanks